# How to include a entity specific property in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am working with Entity Framework. I don't have enough experience to solve any kinds of problem. The problem I am facing now is this: I have two classes as shown here:

```
public class AspNetUser: NormalUser
{
    [Key]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public string PIN { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get { return this.LastName + " , " + this.FirstName; } }
}

public class OfferReview
{
    [Key]
    public string OfferReviewId { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Review { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUser User { get; set; }
}
```

I need to bind all `OfferReview` property with `AspNetUser.FullName` property ==> I tried like this:

```
return context.OfferReviews
              .Where(It => It.OfferId == offerId)
              .Include(it => it.User.FullName)
              .ToList();
```

Here `offerId` is a function parameter. I'm unable to show the full function....

I can easily get the above requirement with the help of linq join. But I want something above like lambda expression.

Is it possible? Or if possible how also if not possible then is there any other way? Please help

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be:

```
return context.OfferReviews
              .Where(It => It.OfferId == offerId)
              .Include(it => it.User)
              .ToList();
```

This return a list of `OfferReview` entities, each having a `User` object in it.

Now in your view you can bind `OfferReview.User.FullName`.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do It By Technique ViewModel

This ViewModel :

```
        public class ViewModel
{
    public string OfferReviewId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Review { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get { return this.LastName + " , " + this.FirstName; } }
}
```

this query:

```
     var query = context.OfferReview
             .Where(It => It.OfferReviewId == "1")
             .Select(p => new ViewModel
                {
                    OfferReviewId = p.OfferReviewId,
                    Review = p.Review,
                    UserId = p.UserId,
                    FirstName = p.User.FirstName,
                    LastName = p.User.LastName
                }).ToList();
```